# Doing Ph.D in another country and Master in Italy at the same time, is it possible?

Tags: phd

Doing Ph.D in another country and Master in Italy at the same time, is it possible? I am already Ph.D student in Armenia and I want to apply for one of Erasmus Mundus Master programs in University of Bologna. Is that possible?

Comment: I would say it is doubtful whether you have the time to do both - though I guess there is nothing stopping you from being enrolled in two courses provided you fulfill the entry requirements for both - and are actually able to give both your attention. This would not really possible if both are full time - if the contents overlap sufficiently for it to be possible, there may be future conflicts as to who contributed what in which work... - You might also want to clarify how you envisage this to work? Are you given leave from the PhD for obtaining a Masters?

Comment: Depends on the rules of your university and the University of Bologna. Ask your advisor and, if they say it's OK by your university's rules, ask the programme director in Bologna.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure of the rules in those specific locations but it was my understanding that you can only be registered on a full time course at one university at a time. This is something you should check with both institutions.

Further to this, do you really think you would have the time to study for a Masters and a PhD at the same time and if you did do both then could you honestly say you were dedicating yourself 100% to one or the other? A PhD is not something to be done on a whim and requires a huge effort on the part of the student to complete.